# Append on XML element using Python

Tags: python, xml

I have xml named user_data.xml that contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<users>
<user name="Rocky" id="1" age="38"/>
<user name="Steve" id="2" age="50"/>
<user name="Melinda" id="3" age="38"/>
</users>
```

and i want to add new element inside users something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<users>
<user name="Rocky" id="1" age="38"/>
<user name="Steve" id="2" age="50"/>
<user name="Melinda" id="3" age="38"/>
<user name="Yondu" id="4" age="55"/>
</users>
```

and I've tried to do it using this python code:

```
class add_user:
        root_new  = ET.Element("users") 
    root_new.append((ET.fromstring('<user name="Yondu" id="4" age="55"/>')))
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root_new)
    tree.write(sys.stdout)
    for c in root_new:
        print(root_new)
```

but it's not working .

Any idea on how can I do it?

Comment: u r using `xml.etree.ElementTree` library ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse input XML file/content by `etree.fromstring()`
2. Now you get object of root element.
3. Then use etree.Element() method to create New User element.
4. As our root element is `users` i.e. append new element to `root` element by `append` method.

**Demo**:

```
>>> from lxml import etree

>>> input_data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
... <users>
... <user name="Rocky" id="1" age="38"/>
... <user name="Steve" id="2" age="50"/>
... <user name="Melinda" id="3" age="38"/>
... </users>"""

>>> root = etree.fromstring(input_data)

>>> new_user = etree.Element("user", {"name":"Yondu", "id":"4", "age": "55"})

>>> root.tag
'users'

>>> root.append(new_user)

>>> print etree.tostring(root, method="xml", pretty_print=True)
<users>
<user name="Rocky" id="1" age="38"/>
<user name="Steve" id="2" age="50"/>
<user name="Melinda" id="3" age="38"/>
<user age="55" name="Yondu" id="4"/></users>

>>>
```

Note: Do necessary Exception handle.

[lxml Documentation Link](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)